# how to format HTML Emails with bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, email, twitter-bootstrap-3

Example this one (the actual email content):

```
<section><div class="m_-5028752718443096113row">
        <div class="m_-5028752718443096113col-sm-6">
        <section><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the river</p>
</section></div>
        <div class="m_-5028752718443096113col-sm-6">
        <section><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the riverThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the river</p>
</section></div>
    </div></section>
```

The col class has been changed and a prefix has been added. (This is my first time sending emails with bootstrap classes on it)

If I include the bootstrap cdn class in the email would it still be able to recognize it's classes even though they were changed?

Comment: not sure email will recognize external css styles. I think we have to add all inline styles for emails.

Comment: So bootstrap should be inline in the header for it to work? Hmm seems like a lot of trouble for styling emails.